# Call model from another plugin in Strapi

Tags: strapi

I have a `Notification` model which `belongsToMany` users from `users-permissions` plugin.

I have another model called `Profile` which `belongsToOne` user.

Now, I want to `populate` the notification with related `user` and their `profile` ...

I have tried:

```
 await strapi.query("user", "users-permissions").find({_id: `model id`}).populate('profile')
```

Throwing `Impossible to find the plugin where strapi.query has been called.` at me.

Also tried:

```
notification.user.populate('profile')
```

No luck either

I also tried `strapi.plugins["users-permissions"].models.user` got undefined!

Comment: BTW to work around this, and due to the lack of documentation, i'm consuming strapi apis with `axios` 

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `query`.

You will have to use the mongoose model instance of the `User` model of `Users & Permissions` plugin.

```
return strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].models.user.
  .findOne(user_id)
  .populate('profile');
```

Comment: Thank you @Jim, sorry I got undefined from `strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].models.user`

Comment: Try to log `strapi` then `strapi. plugins` then `strapi.plugins['users-permissions']`
I think you will find the `user` model you search.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem here.
All of these are undefined:

```
strapi.query
strapi.plugins
```

The global `strapi` object exists, just doesn't provide the properties listed above...
Am I missing something? I have read the docs at least three times... no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Global `strapi` object do not have either plugins or query properties.

All `strapi` object has is as shown in screenshot.

[image: All strapi object has is as shown in screenshot]

Please note that I am trying to query plugin model from:

**/admin/src/containers/HomePage/index.js**

Comment: Is this meant as an answer according to [answer]? It seems more like a description of what you want than an attempt to help with the quesiton at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works on the backend side, whilst you are trying to reach it from the front end