# How do I use strapi.query from within my custom admin plugin (UI)?

Tags: strapi

I have created a blank plugin via `strapi generate:plugin test`. Everything was created just fine and the menu item in strapi backoffice appears as expected. I have also created a custom content type "product" via strapi UI.

Now I want to query existing products from a custom view provided by my custom plugin.
I have read the documentation twice. It always suggests to use a global strapi object to access a query function `strapi.query(...)`.

The (global) strapi object exists, but it does NOT provide the query function... What am I missing?

Comment: Hello! I just tried and it works well.
Here is a short video of what I did : https://www.loom.com/share/66cf239f05394cb1bf130d366f19ab42
Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. But here is another thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864795/call-model-from-another-plugin-in-strapi/65945794#65945794.

Comment: Posted an answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789460/strapi-how-to-get-data-from-admin-controller-in-admin-ui/76026086#76026086